# Htaccess Regular expression to match any character

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I am using this regular expression on my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L,NC]
```

The problem is this works with any variation of this:

```
example.com/search/test product 123
example.com/search/test+product+123
example.com/search/testproduct123
example.com/search/test%20product%20123
```

But when I throw a period (.) into it it doesn't match and I get a 404 message. I'm a rookie to regular expression and cannot figure out the syntax to add to [A-Za-z0-9_-\s] to allow all characters. I believe [.*] would work but it still send me to a 404.I want to allow period in the rewrite rule with what I currently have.

## Updated:

So how would I take this:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$
```

And allow it to recognize a string like this:

```
search/st.+charles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow a dot (.) you have to escape it, so use `\.` instead of `.`. You can also use `[^abc]` to allow all characters but *abc*.

## Edit:

To allow dots in the path, use this:

`^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)/?$`

Comment: I want to allow period in the rewrite rule with what I currently have.

So how would I take this:  ^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?$

And allow it to recognize a string like this: search/st.+charles

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)([/]*)$