# When URL Rewriting, how to match any Unicode character?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, unicode, url-rewriting

I have this `.htaccess.` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

This rule work fine for a-z, A-Z, and 0-9, but I want that the rule matches every any Unicode character. I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144510/htaccess-regular-expression-to-match-any-character):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)?/?([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026213/php-regex-any-character):

```
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)/?([\s\S]*)?/?([\s\S]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

but it doesn't seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you very much my friend!

Comment: Hey @anubhave! Until now it worked perfectly, but suddenly I get an error. Until now I just used `$_GET["controller"]`, `$_GET["action"]`, `$_GET["id"]` without checking if it exists because the `.htaccess` set it in the first place. But suddenly it gives me an error: `Notice: Undefined index: id`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure why but try: **`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]`**

Comment: Still the same error. But when I delete the line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d it works fine.

Comment: That mean your URL is a real directory in that case remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line

Comment: Works great. Thanks. But how could it be that it worked before and now it dosen't? Since I haven't change anything...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94539/discussion-between-sipo-and-anubhava).